# Vue: Change webpack application build path for use in subdirectory on website

Tags: vuejs2

I have a vue application that I need to add to a subdirectory on an existing website. Example: www.somesite.com/subdirectory/vue_application_here

My webpack file looks like this:

I though changing the public path to match the subdirectory would work, but nothing seems to change when I edit it.

What do I need to change in my webpack config so that when it builds, it no longer looks for my files in the site root, and rather looks for them in the subdirectory?

Note that this is a very simple application so I am not using vue-router.

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

**Edit:** I seem to have gotten it working without having to change the webpack file. I simply had to change the path to the main.js file in the index from /dist/build.js to dist/build.js so it looks in the current subdirectory vs the site root.

Comment: If you want to build from the sub directory, update the entry file path so that it points to the correct file? Right now you’re building from the root directory’s src folder (assuming that this config is in the root directory). `output.path` and `output.publicPath` dictates the output of the build process, not the input.

Comment: So if I change publicPath: '/dist/', to publicPath: 'dist/', it should look in that directory vs. the site root, correct?

Comment: Public path only determines what url to inject in the browser. It has nothing to do with the build process. Read the docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath. Your entry file is the one that contains the info to build a tree that tells webpack where all the other files used for building can be found.

Comment: Well. I seem to have gotten it working without having to change the webpack file.

I simply had to change the path to the main.js file in the index from /dist/build.js to dist/build.js so it looks in the current subdirectory vs the site root.